# Hide a div in while user session exists

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have this problem: I can't find out how to hide a div that appears just when session begins. So I a have a X button for closing, and when the page is refreshed, the div appears again! But I don't want to stop the session.
My code:

```
<div id="got-points" style="display:<?php echo (isset($customer) && !empty($customer) && isset($customer['customer']) && !empty($customer['customer'])) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"> // Checks if session is active
<div class="got-points-bg" style="display: visible;">
    <div class="got-points-box">
        <img class="got-points-close" src="<?php echo base_url();?>static/images/i8.png" /> //Close Button

           My text here

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And js

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".got-points-close").click(function() {
            $(".got-points-bg").hide("fast");
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is on refresh then it is easy; just do it in the PHP session; like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="got-points" style="display:<?php echo (isset($customer) && !empty($customer) && isset($customer['customer']) && !empty($customer['customer']) && empty($_SESSION['first_load'])) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"> // Checks if session is active
<div class="got-points-bg" style="display: visible;">
    <div class="got-points-box">
        <img class="got-points-close" src="<?php echo base_url();?>static/images/i8.png" /> //Close Button

           My text here

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your PHP before then (like on login/session start) - this will obviously need significant editing since you haven't included your PHP I can't guess it very well, but this should provide a starting point:

```
<?php
    //load user check pseudo code
    if !empty($_SESSION[user]) and whatever other checks... {
        $_SESSION['first_load'] = False; //important line number 2
    }
    //login pseudo code to demonstrate placement within your code
    if user & pass = valid {
        $_SESSION['first_load'] = True; //important line number one
    }
```

That is assuming you want th div output but not displayed on subsequent loads.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, how about something like this?

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['variable'])){
    sleep(3); /* Duration(in seconds) div is displayed for */
    echo
    "<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".got-points-bg").hide("fast");
        });
   </script>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php error_reporting(0); session_start(); if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) echo "<div id='togglediv'> My text here </div>"; ?>
```

hope it will work